# Prove Matrix Correspondence is NP-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

Consider the following problem. Given a $m \times n$ integer matrix $A$ and a $p \times q$ integer matrix $B$, do there exist one-to-one functions 
$$r:\{1,2,...,m\} \rightarrow \{1,2,...,p\}$$
$$c:\{1,2,...,n\} \rightarrow \{1,2,...,q\}$$
where for all $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$, $A[i,j] \leq B[r(i),c(j)]$?

What is the best way to show this problem is NP-complete? I am currently considering reducing the clique problem to this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned, we can reduce maximum clique problem to this. In fact we can reduce the more general [subgraph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) to this one easily. Given graphs $G$ and $H$, define $A$ and $B$ as their (undirected) incidence matrices. Then we can see that solving the matrix correspondence tells whether $G$ is isomorphic to some subgraph of $H$, which is an NP-complete problem.